# Include only certain categories in the Woocommerce wc_get_loop_prop product loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm building a custom category archive template using `archive-product.php` as a base. What I need to do is show only products from some categories by using the ID of the product category (which is `product_cat` in Woocommerce). But I want to use `wc_get_products` rather than a `WP_Query` post loop, re: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

> "wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query provide a standard way of
> retrieving products that is safe to use and will not break due to
> database changes in future WooCommerce versions. Building custom
> WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future
> versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better
> performance."

I've copied `archive-product.php` to the woocommerce folder in my child theme and renamed it `custom-category-archive.php`, and it has a header of

```
/*
Template Name: Custom Category Archive Template
*/
```

so I can select it as a page template in the page editor.

This is the original Woocommerce product loop in the new template `custom-category-archive.php`:

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

How do I modify the loop to include only the products in the product category (`product_cat`) by using the category ID? This is how a new WP_Query post loop includes only the products which are in the product categories `12, 345, 7899`:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'terms'     => array('12,345,7899'),   // including categories by ID
            'operator'  => 'IN',
        )
```

How do I include product categories, i.e. like `12, 345, 7899`, in the `wc_get_loop_prop('total')` post product loop in my `custom-category-archive.php` template to show only products in those three product categories?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a `WP_Query` that returns products from certain categories. Now you want the same query to only returns the `ids` not the entire data? Is that what you're asking? Can you explain in a clear way?

Comment: Thanks, to clarify, I want to return the products in those categories using the category ID. But I want to use the wc_get_loop_prop loop rather than a new WP_Query, if possible. Maybe it's simpler and easier to use WP_Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing this outline https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/, this is a basic loop for a category archive using `wc_get_products`:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>

<?php


  if(!function_exists('wc_get_products')) {
    return;
  }


  $cat_terms = get_field('add_categories_custom_template', $term->term_id);


  $ordering              = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
  $ordering['orderby']   = array_shift(explode(' ', $ordering['orderby']));
  $ordering['orderby']   = stristr($ordering['orderby'], 'price') ? 'meta_value_num' : $ordering['orderby'];
 
  $cat_products         = wc_get_products(array(
    'stock_status'      => 'instock',
    'visibility'        => 'visible',
    'status'            => 'publish',
    'limit'             => -1,
    'paginate'          => true,
    'return'            => 'ids',
    'orderby'           => $ordering['orderby'],
    'order'             => $ordering['order'],

    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field'         => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => array('123,45,6789'),
            'operator'      => 'IN',
        )
   )

  ));


 wc_set_loop_prop('total', $cat_products->total);

  if($cat_products) {
    do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');

    echo '<div id="container">';

      foreach($cat_products->products as $cat_product) {

        $post_object = get_post($cat_product);
        setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);

        echo '<div '; wc_product_class( ' ', $product ); echo '>'; 

            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

        echo '</div>';

      }
      wp_reset_postdata();

echo '</div>';

    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
  } else {
    do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
  }


do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try like is -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
             'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
             'terms'     => array(12,345,7899),   // including categories by ID
             'operator'  => 'IN',
         )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    print the_title(); 
    the_excerpt(); 
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: My question is I want to use wc_get_loop_prop, not WP_Query.

Comment: Before get( wc_get_loop_prop ) you have to set ( wc_set_loop_prop ) . see refrence(The Custom WooCommerce Product Loop) URL:  https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/